# What are the extreme points of the closed unit ball of $C$? .

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

What are the extreme points of the closed unit ball of C(the space of all continuous functions on the unit interval), with the supremum norm?

Comment: what is $C$?....

Answer (score 0):

The extreme points of the closed unit ball of $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ are $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=-1$.

It is easy to verify that $f$ and $g$ are extreme points. For the converse, let $h$ so that $|h(x)|<1$ on an open set $V$ (by continuity). By Urysohn's lemma we can construct a function $k$ such $\|h\pm k\|<1$ and $\|k\|<1$. Then we can write $h=\frac{1}{2}(h-g)+\frac{1}{2}(h+g)$ and $h$ is not an extreme point.

Comment: Are you assuming all functions are real-valued?

Comment: Yes I've implicitly made this assumption.